# Understanding Fiddler grabbed network traffic to build HTTP Client

Tags: java, http, cookies, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse engineer a web app (which uses flash object to communicate with server). I have grabbed the network traffic via fiddler i.e., Browsed the app using IE and captured network traffic in Fiddler. This first time i am doing something this so i might be asking very basic questions :(

Now, I have those events/requests in Fiddler but I am having hard time understanding them (besides basic HTTP requests). So I am going to post the traffic flow and then its respective traffic here and at the end the questions

**FLOW ON IE**

- Entered the url website.com/app/app-subdomain/web-app
- An HTML page is displayed with user & password request
- After login, an HTML page is displayed with Flash object in it (the original app)

**IN FIDDLER**
(requests in order)

- The first thing i see is request to `URL:www.website.com:443` which results in `200` status. Fiddler shows there are no cookies or whatsoever. Only the "Clients" are there
- The second request i see is to `URL:app/app-subdomain/web-app`. However, here is the part where i am confused at. In fiddler request body, I see a cookie. which is something like this

`GET https://www.website.com/app/app-subdomain/web-app HTTP/1.1`
`Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, \*/\*`

```
Accept-Language: en-US

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: Keep-Alive

Host: www.website.com

Cookie: 

    NAME-WEB-SESSION=akcxxxpxkxfaxdxccajkjumxax; 

    hl=us; 

    dxxxxcxx=0; 

    NAMESSO=fdxdfxdfdxcfabxxxcxxcdbfexxxxfxfxxxefxecxxaxxxxxxefxxxxxxxxfxaxx; 

    XSRF-TOKEN=vXXnjhHE-ptnvmYfKfQVxscHyrGrfbwxyxkGzfWZGoU
```

So far, the thing which is confusing me, is who generated this cookie ? so lets say i am using Apache HTTPClient, would this cookie be generated by it or do I have to ? If i have to, then how to generate the values of those key-value cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what the `first` request was exactly, but more than likely this was just a `HTTP CONNECT` tunnel through which secure traffic flows. You should NEVER see a cookie on a `CONNECT` tunnel. Have you cleared your browser's cookies and cache? If not, the cookie you saw was likely set on a previous visit to the site and stored in the client's cookie jar. If you have cleared the cache and cookies, that implies that something on the client (e.g. Flash) generated the cookie via some other, non-standard, process.

Comment: hmm, thats interesting .. I do remember that i cleared everything but i guess my first visit was hung in the middle so i had to refresh the site. Will try again. Thanks for guidance